# Is the value of a struct variable just an address(like in the case of array)?

Tags: c, pointers

In C the following is legal:

```
int a[] = {27,2};
int *b;
int c;

b = a;
c = *b; /* c == 27 */
```

The point is that a is just the address of the array so I can assign it to a pointer.
Why is the same not true for struct, I would assume that the value of a struct variable is just the address and therefore I should be able to assign it to a pointer as in:

```
struct foo bar;
struct foo *doo;
bar.x = 0;
doo = bar; //is this legal?
doo.x = 0; //why can't I use the dot?
```

In other words if the value of a struct variable is just the address of the first component(and I suppose this is the case like an array) the above code should be legal.

Comment: Yeah as LihO says, arrays are special. They are the only thing that is... Structures are not.

Comment: Array can be treated as a pointer to its first element. `b = a` is then equal to `b = &a[0]`. `struct`s are different, you need to use address operator explicitly: `doo = &bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the semantics for arrays are different than for structs.  As for *why* that's the case, you have to remember that C was derived from earlier languages ([BCPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCPL) and [B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_%28programming_language%29)), both of which were "typeless" languages that saw memory as a linear array of fixed-length "words" or "cells".  In those older languages, when you declared an array like

```
auto V[10];
```

11 memory cells were set aside; one for an object named `V`, and then 10 more for the array elements; the address of the first element of the array was stored in `V`.

From Dennis Ritchie's paper [The Development of the C Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html):

> Problems became evident when I tried to extend the type notation, especially to add structured (record) types. Structures, it seemed, should map in an intuitive way onto memory in the machine, but in a structure containing an array, there was no good place to stash the pointer containing the base of the array, nor any convenient way to arrange that it be initialized. For example, the directory entries of early Unix systems might be described in C as
>
> ```
> struct {
>     int     inumber;
>     char    name[14];
> };
> ```
>
> **I wanted the structure not merely to characterize an abstract object but also to describe a collection of bits that might be read from a directory.** Where could the compiler hide the pointer to name that the semantics demanded? Even if structures were thought of more abstractly, and the space for pointers could be hidden somehow, how could I handle the technical problem of properly initializing these pointers when allocating a complicated object, perhaps one that specified structures containing arrays containing structures to arbitrary depth?
>
> The solution constituted the crucial jump in the evolutionary chain between typeless BCPL and typed C. **It eliminated the materialization of the pointer in storage, and instead caused the creation of the pointer when the array name is mentioned in an expression.** The rule, which survives in today's C, is that values of array type are converted, when they appear in expressions, into pointers to the first of the objects making up the array.

Emphasis mine.  This is why array expressions in C are treated differently from all other expression types, including struct types.

Answer (score 3):

> The point is that `a` is just the address of the array so I can assign it to a pointer.

That's not quite right: compiler *converts* the name of an array to a pointer that points to the array's initial element. This happens automatically, without requiring a cast or an "address of" operator `&`. However, `a` is **not** just the address, which is evidenced by taking its size with `sizeof(a)`.

This should explain why the same is not true for `struct` (i.e. because it is not so for arrays). For `struct`s, the "address of" operator `&` is mandatory:

```
doo = &bar;
```

> doo.x = 0; //why can't I use the dot?

C has a different syntax for accessing `struct`s elements through a pointer: you need to use the `->` operator instead of a dot `.` operator.

Comment: If you ask "why did C chose to add a new operator `->` instead of allowing to use the `.` with pointers as well, my answer would be "I don't know". As far as I know, there would have been no technical issues with that.

Answer (score 1):

> doo = bar; //is this legal?

No, Try:

```
doo = & bar;
     ^^
```

> doo.x = 0; //why can't I use the dot?

Because `doo` is a pointer. Try:

```
doo->x = 0;
   ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. What you want to do is:

```
doo = &bar; 
doo->x = 0;
```

In case of arrays it works because an array of `T` is implicitly convertible to `T*`, but this is not the case for structs. A pointer may store the address of your struct objext (`&bar`). In order to access struct elements indirectly with a pointer one should use the -> operator. `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`

Answer (score 1):

```
  doo = bar; //is this legal?
```

No, it is not valid. The left operand is of a structure type and the right operand is of a pointer type.

This is legal:

```
 doo = &bar;
```

`&bar` is of type pointer to `struct foo`.

Now:

```
  doo.x = 0; //why can't I use the dot?
```

because the operand has to be of a structure type but it is of a pointer type. Use `->` to access elements from an object of pointer to structure type.

```
  doo->x = 0;  // this is valid
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the value of a struct is the struct itself, not its address. This allows you to do something like this:

```
struct foo a;
struct foo b;
b = a;  /* this does a memberwise copy of all fields from a to b */
```

If you want the address of the struct, use the `&` operator:

```
struct foo a;
struct foo* b = &a
struct foo c;
c = *b;  /* this does a memberwise copy of all fields from a to c */
```